# Impératif par deux personnes

Tags: grammaire, sens, usage, impératif

Je suis troublée par l’usage de nous et tu dans l’impératif car je ne sais quand remplacer nous par tu.

A et B parle de Gilbert
A: C’est la fête de Gilbert dimanche, tu sais?
B: Oui, (inviter) invite-le à dîner au restaurant.

Ou la personne B peut dire « invitons-le »?

Comment: Qui invite ? :  si A se rendra seul à cet anniversaire → singulier : s'ils (A & B) y vont ensemble au restaurant → pluriel

Answer (score 2):

Sans faute de ma part, je crois que tout dépend de ce que l'interlocuteur B veut dire. S'il(elle) veut exprimer un ordre/commande/requête/demande/conseil destiné à A, il peut utiliser l'impératif du 2nd person du singulier. S'il(elle) veut rendre en français l'anglais "let's..." il(elle) peut dire "invitons-le".